# Understanding a calculator: what does "sign" mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology, definition, calculator

I put the following input into a ti-nspire cx CAS:

[image]

and it returned:

[image]

What does "sign" mean?

Comment: cf. [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function):  sgn$(t)=-1$ if $t<0$, $0$ if $t=0$, and $1$ if $t>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the sign of $t$, which is $+1$ if $t$ is positive, $0$ if $t$ is $0$, and $-1$ if $t$ is negative.

Comment: I don't understand - it's just telling me t is negative?

Comment: No.  It is a function.  Examples:  $sign(-7) = -1$, $sign(+48) = +1$.

Comment: No. $t$ could be positive, in which case the $\cos(\pi t)$ term is positive.  If $t$ is negative, the $\cos(\pi t)$ term has a minus sign in front of it.

Comment: It's telling you that the result depends on whether $t$ is positive, $0$, or negative.  If $t>0$ then $sign\, t = 1.$  If $t=0,$ then $sign\, t = 0$.  If $t<0$, then $sign\, t =-1.$

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{sign}:\mathbb R \to \{-1, 0 , 1\}$.

$$\operatorname{sign}(x) = \begin{cases}-1& \text{if }x < 0\\0&\text{if }x =0\\1&\text{ if } x > 0.\end{cases}$$

Basically, it returns the "sign of $x$".

What this is saying is that if $t > 0$ then we get in the numerator $\pi\cos(\pi t) - \pi|t|\sin(\pi t) = \pi\cos(\pi t) - \pi  t\sin(\pi t)$

But if $t < 0$ then we get in the numerator $-\pi\cos(\pi-t) -\pi|t|\sin(\pi t)=-\pi\cos(\pi t) + \pi t\sin(\pi t)$

I guess if I weren't a machine I'd put this as $\pm(\pi\cos(\pi t) - \pi t\sin(\pi t))$ where the $\pm$ is determined by the sign of $t$.

Or simply:  $\operatorname{sign}(t)\cdot[\pi\cos(\pi t) - \pi t\sin(\pi t)]$.